# C# Can FileSystemWatcher fire if the watched directory isn't empty on startup?

Tags: c#, directory, filesystemwatcher

Basically, I've got this program which checks for changes in a directory and if anything is copied or created into said directory some stuff happens. This works fine.
But I want the code to fire if the watched directory isn't empty when the program is launched, is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check yourself:

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(yourPath).Length != 0)
{
    //trigger your action
}
//else?
//set up the FileSystemWatcher
```

Comment: Seems sound enough, but I've got multiple watchers, this means I'll have to create an if-statement for each watcher and basically copy-paste the watcher code into there, right? Is there a way to do this without doubling all of my code? Or is there a way to trigger the FileSystemWatcher manually perhaps?

Comment: @ChristopherSirén Yes, just call the method that the `FileSystemWatcher` triggers.

Comment: here is the scenario:
At the time of launching of the program, the directory that is being watched already has some items. These items must also be 'processed'. Since the directory change events are not going to be fired, so I thought I would do it manually

Comment: @Marci-man The trick is to have processing done in a separate method, which both your manual check and the `FileSystemWatcher` call.